KMP Kotlin MultiPlatform Compose google Login iOS is not working with Shared UI
I started working in Kotlin MultiPlatform Compose KMP with shared UI.
I need to login with google on both (Android and iOS) side.
I followed these tutorials
1) google Sign In
2) CMP Google Login
3) Compose MultiPlatform Login with Google
4) MultiPlatform Initialising Firebase
and
5) KMP Auth With the help of this Library application get crashed.
Using the above tutorials I logged in with the google at the Android Side successfully, but unable to run the application using Xcode for iOS. It was giving me error same as this. It is the accepted answer but very unclear how to solve this.
The main problem of mine is google login iOS side. but right now I am unable to run the app on iOS side with cocoapods.
Kindly help me out or guide me in the right direction.
I can give the deep insight, if you want or you think, somethings is missing in the question.
